# package mysql56-server is not installed

Tags: amazon-web-services

Amazon Linux

```
% yum info mysql56-server
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1011 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Available Packages
Name        : mysql56-serve
...
```

`yum info` show the information.
but `rpm -qi` not show.

```
% rpm -qi mysql56-server
package mysql56-server is not installed
```

why `rpm -qi` not show the information.

Comment: is it amazon linux ami?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki yes

Comment: I would suggest take a standard ami like ubuntu 16 or 14 or fedora whatever you prefer. Using amazon linux ami is just the start of trouble regarding package installation and management

Comment: @ArpitSolanki, true in past i had lot of trouble with amazon linux ami.